# Changing number of available slots in running SGE Instance

Tags: sungridengine, starcluster

I would like to change the number of slots on a running SGE instance. The instance was started by StarCluster.

I tried following this [page](http://wwwx.cs.unc.edu/Research/bass/index.php/Administrators:SGE:Common_Tasks#Setting_slot_.23_to_0) and running:

```
ubuntu@master: $ qconf -mattr exechost complex_values slots=1 master
ubuntu@master modified "master" in exechost list
```

but it does not look like anything changed:

```
ubuntu@master: $ qstat -f
queuename                      qtype resv/used/tot. load_avg arch          states
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
all.q@master                   BIP   0/1/8          1.04     linux-x64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run

```
qconf -mq all.q
```

Then you will see a line

```
slots                 1,[master=0],[node1366=2],[node1379=2]
```

If you want master to have 1 slot, change it to

```
[master=1]
```

Save and quit. That's as simple as that.